# Change particular characters (escape characters) in a string by using regex or indexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I'm trying to change particular characters such as `[ ', ", \ ]` because I have a problem during INSERT. For example, the string `I'm saying "Hi"` will be `I\'m saying \"Hi\"`. So basically this method is adding `backslash` in front of the characters. But I'm not sure how to do this with regex.

I was thinking to do this with `IndexOf` but the index of the string is changed when I add the `backslash` to the string.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
str = 'I\'m saying "Hi" \\ abc';
str = str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').replace(/(['"])/g, '\\$1');
```

but if you're using SQL, I would really look into prepared statements: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: How do you know that I'm using Node.js? Thank you! That link is exatly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$1` the `$` means "saved group", and `1` means the first saved group:

So:

```
string.replace( /(['"\\])/g, "\\$1" )
```

How this works is:

```
/           Start RegEx
  (         Start "saved" or capturing group
    ['"\\]  Matches any of the characters between []
  )         End "saved" group
/g          End RegEx, g means "global" which means it will match multiple times instead of just the first
```